# Shake text effect on Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to stop this shake effect after three shake. Is it possible to use set or clearInterval on this one? Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
        function interval() {
          $('#shake').effect('shake', {
            times: 3
          }, 100);
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var shake = setInterval(interval, 1200);
        });
```

```html
<div id="shake">This Text is Shaking</div>
```

Comment: maybe try [hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify interval method to:

```
var executedcoount=0;
function interval() {
      if(executedcoount<3){
      $('#shake').effect('shake', {
        times: 3
      }, 100);
      executedcoount++;
     }
    }
```